# IsConnectedToNetwork for Windows8 WinRT Fails

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Anyone know a good way to see if the user is online/offline? When I use public static bool IsConnectedToNetwork(); and see if it's false/true it seems to always be true, even when I shut down my internet to test it...

Am I missing something?

```
public static bool nets()
{
    bool go = 
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();

    if (go == false)
    {
        return false;  
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, in my start-up I run:

```
var ba = nets();

if (ba == false)
{
    txtHeader.Text = "err";
}
if (ba != false)
{
    // Code
}
```

I also tried:

```
    public static bool IsConnectedToNetwork();
```

Comment: I believe that IsConnectedToNetwork() returns true if the network adapter is connected to a network, *not* if you have internet connectivity.

Comment: I actually have tried this... It comes back as a false positive. If you look at my updated code you'll see what I mean...

Comment: Have you looked at the network status changed sample (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Network-Information-Sample-63aaa201/view/SourceCode#content)? It has code to do exactly what you're asking about (and includes internet vs local network connectivity)

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
public static bool IsConnectedToInternet()
{
    ConnectionProfile connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    return (connectionProfile!=null && connectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);

 }
```

Comment: Seems not liking me... I tried to see if it was null and tells me I can't use "==" operators.

Comment: what and why do you test for null? Just copy this method to your code and call it

Answer (score 0):

You could ping one of the few well known URLs to see if you get responses.

Comment: To be honest, I can't find "Ping" in any of the includes (using Windows.Networking.Connectivity,
using System.Net.NetworkInformation, or 
using Windows.Networking.Sockets)...

Comment: I think he meant that generically as in make a web request to bing.com and see what comes back

Answer (score 0):

I have a way that seems to work pretty decent, especially noticing sometimes Ethernet could appear to be in use even when its not in Windows 8 RTM... That's why nothing seems to work!

However, doing the following is a good choice for me to test...

```
    var profile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

         var interfaceType = profile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType;
            // 71 is WiFi & 6 is Ethernet
            if (interfaceType == 71 | interfaceType == 6) 
            {
              // Run Code
            }
            /* 3G/Mobile Detect
            else if (interfaceType == 243 | interfaceType == 244)
            {
              // Run Code if you need to use a less quality feature.
            }*/
            else
            {
                txtHeader.Text = "Error, Check connection or Try connecting to the Internet...";
            }
```